# Integral using divergence theorem

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I am trying to evaluate this integral using divergence theorem.

$$\int_{R_\infty}\nabla_R \cdot J_R R dR$$
where
$R=\hat{i}x+\hat{j}y$,
$R_\infty=((x,y)|-\infty<x,y<\infty)$,
$\nabla_R=\hat{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$,
$J_R=-D\nabla_RP+\hat{e}VP$,
$\hat{e}=\hat{i}+\hat{j}$, $P$ is variable, $D, V$ are constants.

Is it wise to use integration by parts but then I need to know how to evaluate $\int_{R_\infty}\nabla_R \cdot J_R dR$ this first?

Comment: We need more information about $P$.

Comment: $P$ depends on $x,y$.